# Download public dropbox file with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dropbox

I have a public txt file on dropbox with a version string, for example `2017.09.01`. I tested the download with curl

```
curl -v -L http://www.dropbox.com/s/ehoawgm89yz6pib/version.txt?raw=1
```

and it does work. It requires `-L` for redirection. I don't know much about curl but I do see the redirection `HTTP/2 302` then the normal request

```
< HTTP/2 200
< content-disposition: inline; filename="version.txt"; filename*=UTF-8''version.txt
< ...
<
2017.09.01
* Connection #1 to host dl.dropboxusercontent.com left intact
```

Then I tried with Qt with a pretty simple request class, something like:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
  auto manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
  QNetworkRequest request(checkURL);
  connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
    this, &MyClass::replyFinished);

  m_Reply = manager->get(request);
}

void MyClass::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
  QUrl redirect =
    reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
  if (redirect.isValid() && reply->url() != redirect)
  {
    if (redirect.isRelative())
    {
      redirect = reply->url().resolved(redirect);
    }
    reply->manager()->get(QNetworkRequest(redirect));
    return;
  }

  const auto newVersion = QString(reply->readAll());
  // Do something with the version
}
```

While debuging, I see the redirect, which calls `replyFinished` again, but then there nothing on `readAll`. Always an empty string.

**Before posting an answer**, please test with the link I provide! My code already work for most other links.

Comment: Check [this out](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_Downloading_Files_QNetworkAccessManager_QNetworkRequest.php). I tested this example and worked directly. Not with your link but it worked with other links.

Comment: I read this example before asking my question. My code also work with other links.

Comment: I have tried the code that comments @apalomery and if you download the file you mention.

Comment: I have waxed the code that you provide and I have been able to execute it successfully, obtaining the following: `QUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehoawgm89yz6pib/version.txt?raw=1")
QUrl("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/qdWtaffw8D12BrSySNkxdVxNyEgGhAUJcmvLQjOggXVxDuCEfaPWoBdnri75kfnC/file")
finished
"2017.09.01\n"`

Comment: Good! Can you post your answer with the actual code then? This generated URL is only usable by you so your comment doesn't me much :)

Comment: In the next link is my test, it would be nice to check your firewall @Nil https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/cf6c61eae879b7a5a2902b49d0ed1841

Comment: I posted the link and tell me if it worked

Comment: Right, thank you for your help. My code wasn't the problem, it was Windows and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I tend to ignore some warnings because there's some of them that I can't fix. Turns out these warnings weren't useless! It should be an error, not a warning.

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
```

You must install OpenSSL on [Windows](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries) or use your package manager on other OS. Otherwise, the `reply` object simply return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are off by default. Here is a code snippet that should work:

```
auto manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

QObject::connect(manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished,
        [&](QNetworkReply* repl) {
    qDebug() << repl->readAll();
});
QNetworkRequest req(QUrl("http://www.dropbox.com/s/ehoawgm89yz6pib/version.txt?raw=1"));
req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
req.setMaximumRedirectsAllowed(3);
QNetworkReply* reply = manager->get(req);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work. Always an empty string. I gave the link to my txt file so people could test before posting an answer. Did you test with my link?

Comment: +1 for "Mac OS". It helped me find the problem, which was simply that I need to install OpenSSL on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: I would still use the built-in redirection instead of building my own...

Comment: In Qt6 QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute was removed, https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/network-changes-qt6.html#redirect-policies